# How do I sketch a set and find its edge? How do I decide whether the following set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open, complete, limited, or compact?

Tags: general-topology

How do I sketch a set and find its edge? How do I decide whether the following set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open, complete, limited, or compact?
$$
A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\left | x \right |+\left | y \right |\leq 4\}
$$

Comment: limited = bounded? Would you write out what your definition of "complete" is? Would that be "closed"?

Answer (score 1):

Open sets:

Intuitively -- open sets have a soft edge.

Mathematically -- for every point in an open set there exists a neighborhood about that point where every point in that neigborhood is in the set.

Closed sets:

Intuition -- Have hard edges.

Math -- Are the complements to open sets.
Closed sets contain all of their limit points.

Compete space: -- There are no gaps or holes.

Math -- every Cauchy sequence in the space, converges to a point in the space.

Compact space:-- This took me a while to get my head around.

Intuition -- the next best thing to being finite.

Math -- Every open cover has a finite sub cover.

Every compact set is closed and bounded (but not every closed and bounded set is compact)

A compact set is complete, but a complete set is is not necessarily compact.

In a compact set, every sequence has a convergent sub-sequence to a point in that space.

In the case at hand.

You have a hard edge (less than or equal to).

You are bounded.

The complement is open.

the set is closed.

there are no gaps or holes.

The set is compact.